# JQuery toggle() function

Tags: jquery

I have a problem, When I click on the link p open, and then I click in the other link it doesn't work. It works when I click again.

This is my jQuery code:

```
var toggle = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".feedback_block").each(function () {
        $("a", this).click(function (e) {
            if (toggle == 0) {
                $(this).parent().children("p").stop(true, true).fadeIn(500);
                $(this).addClass("clicked");
                $(this).children().addClass("clicked_span");
                toggle = 1;
                console.log(toggle);
            } else
            if (toggle == 1) {
                $(this).parent().children("p").stop(true, true).fadeOut(500);
                $(this).removeClass("clicked");
                $(this).children().removeClass("clicked_span");
                toggle = 0;
                console.log(toggle);

            }
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        });
        toggle = 0;
    });
});
```

When I click the parameter toggle get `1` and when I click another link the initial value should be 0. How can i do it?

My example: http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/tjzaR/

Comment: I've edited this, but the S/O editor refused about 10 suggested titles (infuriating). Anyone, please improve my (forthcoming) edit.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use toggle() (http://jsfiddle.net/tjzaR/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".feedback_block").each(function () {
        $("a", this).toggle(function (e) {

                $(this).parent().children("p").stop(true, true).fadeIn(500);
                $(this).addClass("clicked");
                $(this).children().addClass("clicked_span");

            }, function(){
                $(this).parent().children("p").stop(true, true).fadeOut(500);
                $(this).removeClass("clicked");
                $(this).children().removeClass("clicked_span");


            });
    });
});
```

or you could do (fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/tjzaR/1/)

```
$(".feedback_block").each(function () {
    $("a", this).click(function (e) {
        if (!$(this).parent().children("p").is(":visible")){
            $(this).parent().children("p").stop(true, true).fadeIn(500);
            $(this).addClass("clicked");
            $(this).children().addClass("clicked_span");

        } else{
            $(this).parent().children("p").stop(true, true).fadeOut(500);
            $(this).removeClass("clicked");
            $(this).children().removeClass("clicked_span");


        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: I know the function toggle(), but there is a way to do this in my code?

Comment: @AramMkrtchyan just remove your `$("a", this).click(function (e) {` with the code above, and remove the toggle variable you created.

Comment: The first method documented here is now deprecated as of jQuery Version 1.9 - Just a heads up

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("a", this).toggle(function () {

                $(this).parent().children("p").stop(true, true).fadeIn(500);
                $(this).addClass("clicked");
                $(this).children().addClass("clicked_span");
                return false; 

            }, function(){

                $(this).parent().children("p").stop(true, true).fadeOut(500);
                $(this).removeClass("clicked");
                $(this).children().removeClass("clicked_span");
                return false;

            });
```

Can we not directly use the toggle function. [Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)